# To specify ftp commands in a file

Tags: ftp, command-line-interface

What is the linux equivalent of -s windows ftp option that specifies a file that contains ftp commands:

```
>ftp -s:C:\ftp-commands.src
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the easiest way should be doing something like this:

```
ftp < command_file.src
```

There isn't any parameter for doing that in linux ftp, but that way you can redirect the content of the file to the command, so the result is the same in essence.

Answer (score 0):

You might also look into cygwin & simply run the linux command the same way that you're accustomed to